# Django: Admin panel not showing all entries when using custom ModelAdmin class

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a simple Django model

```
class Tourney(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Location'), related_name='tourneys')
    date = models.DateField(_('Date'))
    ...
```

When I use this `ModelAdmin` class

```
class TourneyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'date',)
```

the admin panel shows every entry in the database. But when I include the *location* field like

```
class TourneyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'date', 'location',)
```

some entries are not shown in the list.

On the bottom of the page the number of entries (*x Tourneys*) is still shown correctly.

Any idea why that is happening?

Here is the `Location` class:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), unique=True, max_length=50)
```

Comment: I couldn't recreate the behaviour with my models. I think you set everything correctly. Did you perform any migrations and added some of your tourneys before and some of them after that? In this case delete all test tourneys and try create the new ones.

Comment: Could be a weird issue about the string representation of Location model. Can you define `__str__` on Location and test it again.